# Is it possible to send windows logon credentials in XmlHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, xmlhttprequest, windows-authentication

I'm logging into an application on a separate domain and, for each subsequent XmlHttpRequest I make to that domain, I want to send the Windows Authentication credentials so I'm not prompted to login again if I make a request to a separate service on that same domain.

Is it possible to send Windows Authentication credentials in an XmlHttpRequest header?

```
var xmlhttp = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", requestUrl, true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");

//Is it possible to send the Windows Authentication creds in the header of this request?
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("?????", "?????");

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function ()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4)
    {
        callback(__parseJson(xmlhttp.responseText));
    }
}
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

Comment: @Francisc — Why? It's Windows Authentication, it has built in encryption and is probably only being used in a LAN context.

Comment: @Quentin, correct on both counts

Comment: Sending auth data should always be done via HTTPS. Even over LAN. Otherwise you send plain-text user&password pairs. Not sure what Windows Auth is though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to log in using the login domain for each initial request to the different domain. Because the requests are going to a different service then IIS treats it as an initial request and will prompt for the login.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you'd do it as part of the URI:

`http://username:password@webaddress.com`